# Complex Request Object to multiple dto

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am new to this blog, so please excuse me for any mistakes with formating.

I am trying to extract complex object to multiple Dto using Automapper in .net core application.

Started my adventure by using NuGet package "AutoMapper.Extensions.Micorsoft.DependencyInjenction" 11.0.0 version.

Here is my api request looks like:

```
 public class Request
 {
    public string Type{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
    public InnerSource InnerSource { get; set; } 

 }

public class InnerSource
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to convert Request object to 2 separate DTO so that it can be stored to DB through EntityFramework.

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public string Type{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
public class InnerSourceDto
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
}
```

Tried to create a map as below but no success:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>();
CreateMap<Request, InnerSourceDto>().IncludeMembers(src => src.InnerSource);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Call `AssertConfigurationIsValid` and look at the full error message, `exception.ToString()`, it's telling you what's wrong and what to do about it.

Comment: Error says Missing map from InnerSource and InnerSourceDto. Create using CreateMap<InnerSource , InnerSourceDto>.
But how to pass the Request in  CreateMap?

Comment: You don't. You just do what it says and then call `Map`.